# How to get last object of distinct id and different service name from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get last object of

`(id = 1 and serviceName = TapiSrv)`,

`(id = 1 and serviceName = Themes)`,

`(id = 2 and serviceName = TapiSrv)`,

`(id = 2 and serviceName = Themes)`

from array in javascript?

My script, current output and expected result are given below.

At present I am getting only one value of each id.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Script**

```
let services = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StartPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Running"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StartPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Running"
    }     
];
    
const sId = 'id';

const sName = 'serviceName';

const arrayUniqueKey = [...new Map(services.map(item => [item[sId], item])).values()];
    
console.log(arrayUniqueKey);
```

**Current Output**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "serviceName": "Themes",
        "serviceStatus": "Running"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "serviceName": "Themes",
        "serviceStatus": "Running"
    }
]
```

**Expecting Result**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
        "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "serviceName": "Themes",
        "serviceStatus": "Running"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
        "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "serviceName": "Themes",
        "serviceStatus": "Running"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mix `sId` and `sName` for make `key` in `services.map(item => ...`

```js
let services = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StartPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Running"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StartPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "StopPending"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "TapiSrv",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Stopped"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "serviceName": "Themes",
      "serviceStatus": "Running"
    }     
];
    
const sId = 'id';

const sName = 'serviceName';

const arrayUniqueKey = [...new Map(services.map(item => [item[sId]+'-'+item[sName], item]) ).values()];
    
console.log(arrayUniqueKey);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```